# error install matplotlib in cygwin

Tags: python, matplotlib, cygwin

I have tried installing matplotlib into my cygwin environment. Here is the error messages from the installation on my desktop. However this installation is very successful on my laptop. Both use the same version of everything. Anybody has an idea how to fix it?

```
  $ python setup.py install
    basedirlist is: ['/usr/local', '/usr']
    ============================================================================
    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
                matplotlib: 1.1.1
                    python: 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09)  [GCC 4.5.3]
                  platform: cygwin

    REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                     numpy: 1.7.2rc1
                 freetype2: 16.1.10

    OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                    libpng: 1.5.12
    /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
      warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
                      Gtk+: gtk+: 2.24.22, glib: 2.36.4, pygtk: 2.24.0,
                            pygobject: 2.28.6
           Mac OS X native: no
                        Qt: no
                       Qt4: Qt: 4.8.4, PyQt4: 4.10.2
                    PySide: no
                     Cairo: 1.10.0

    OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
                  datetime: present, version unknown
                  dateutil: matplotlib will provide
                      pytz: matplotlib will provide
    adding pytz

    OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                    dvipng: 1.14
          0 [main] python2.7 5112 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'mtrand.dll' (0x410000) is already occupied
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "setup.py", line 227, in <module>
        check_for_ghostscript()
      File "/cygdrive/f/matplotlib-1.1.1/setupext.py", line 513, in check_for_ghostscript
        stdin, stdout = run_child_process(command)
      File "/cygdrive/f/matplotlib-1.1.1/setupext.py", line 228, in run_child_process
        close_fds=(sys.platform != 'win32'))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
        errread, errwrite)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1143, in _execute_child
        self.pid = os.fork()
    OSError: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are installing such an old version of matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

I got matplotlib to work under Cygwin as follows. 1: install libpng from source (using the usual configure, make, make install); 2: install matplotlib with pip install matplotlib (I did have to change the variable name in ._tri, as described here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2463 - then everything worked).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone is unfamiliar of the path like me. The lib is one of the folder from the downloaded matplotlib_XXXversion.gz. After expended the folder and find the _tri.h as well as _tri.cpp, renamed the varilabe _C accroding to post link above. This can then be installed using 
easy_install install filelocation(expended directory of matplotlib_xxxxversion..)